# Can Selenium IDE/Builder run same test case on many pages?

Tags: javascript, selenium, jenkins, automated-tests, selenium-ide

Is there a way to run the same Selenium test case on many pages without specifically defining a list of pages?

Say, for example, I have a UIMap pageset defined like this:

```
var map = new UIMap();
map.addPageset({
    name: 'pages',
    description: 'all pages',
    pathRegexp: '^thisistheroot/$'
});
```

In the pageset, I have all the elements defined for a test script that I want to test on each page in the pageset.
All of this is added to my core extensions.

Am I able to run a test case on the entire pageset? How can I do that?

I've looked into the issue a little more. Is there a way this is possible with Jenkins? https://jenkins-ci.org/

Edit:

I was trying to avoid using selenium webdriver, but if it is possible to obtain links as you would in a UIMap, that would probably point me in the right direction as well. I would try to iterate over the links with a single test case, which can easily be done in java. I'm using java for webdriver by the way.

Thanks.

Comment: I am little confused about the *EDIT* you have done. Are you asking help on `WebDriver` or not?

Comment: I can work with both, but a solution for Selenium IDE is preferred. If `WebDriver` is required, I have the ability to use it. I recently was given permission to use the `WebDriver`, which is why I made the edit.

Comment: So, the idea is to load each pages and iterate over the links present on the page?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to run one test across multiple pages. All pages should have the same locators and should be able to pass the tests I've designed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's simple to run an IDE test against 1 specific page (base url actually): `java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://baseURL.com" "mytestsuite.html" "results.html"`

So what you need to do is use jenkins (or any bash/batch script) to run that command multiple times with the base url set as "http://baseURL.com/page1", "http://baseURL.com/page2", etc.

This will only get you as far as static list of pages to test against. If you want a dynamic list you'd have to also "crawl" the pages and you could do that in the similar batch/bash script to obtain the list of pages to test against.

In this case you'd best be investing beyond selenium IDE and switch to webdriver where you'll have more power to loop and flow control.

Comment: Yes! This is great! This would also allow me to mix together IDE with WebDriver tests, correct?

Comment: my answer is the "correct" one but I don't get the bounty? LOL.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by mix the tests?  I suppose you could if you launched them from command line as well.

Comment: I was trying to spread the reputation equally. Like I said, I wish I could give it to both of you, but Saifur had a very detailed answer that helped me a lot. What I mean by mixing tests is being able to run both in the same Jenkins build. Command line execution of both together was my initial thought as well, that's why I asked. I have some test in IDE and some in WebDriver. I wanted to make it easy for others to use.

Comment: The Page Object Model also made it so I was able to iterate over a list of pages with common elements. (One superclass that has subclasses to iterate over)That is the primary reason for splitting the reputation.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is "no" but `Selenium WebDriver` is one of the best choices for sure to find the links of a page and iterate over them. There is a very similar concept of your *UIMapping* called [PageFactory](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) where you map all the page elements in separate classes to keep the responsibility separate which makes debugging and refactoring much easier. I have used the PageFactory concept [here](https://github.com/safrrhmn/SeleniumTestNG).

Now coming back to your question, you can easily find the list of the links present in a page. In that case you just need to write the selector little carefully. You can then easily iterate over the links and come back and forth and so on.

**Proof of concept on Google**

**BasePage**

```
package google;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/**
 * Defines the generic methods/functions for PageObjects.
 */
public class BaseClass {

    protected WebDriver driver;

    /**
     * @param _driver
     * @param byKnownElement
     */
    public BaseClass(WebDriver _driver, By byKnownElement) {

        //assigning driver instance globally.
        driver = _driver;
        this.correctPageLoadedCheck(byKnownElement);

        /* Instantiating all elements since this is super class
        and inherited by each and every page object */
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    /**
     * Verifies correct page was returned.
     *
     * @param by
     */
    private void correctPageLoadedCheck(By by) {

        try {

            driver.findElement(by).isDisplayed();

        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

**PageObject inherited BasePage**

```
package google;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Saifur on 5/30/2015.
 */
public class GoogleLandingPage extends BaseClass {


    private static final By byKnownElement = By.xpath("//a[text()='Sign in']");

    /**
     * @param _driver
     */

    public GoogleLandingPage(WebDriver _driver) {
        super(_driver, byKnownElement);
    }

    //This should find all the links of the page
    //You need to write the selector such a way
    // so that it will grab all intended links.
    @FindBy(how = How.CSS,using = ".gb_e.gb_0c.gb_r.gb_Zc.gb_3c.gb_oa>div:first-child a")
    public List<WebElement> ListOfLinks;
}
```

**BaseTest**

```
package tests;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

public class BaseTest {


    public WebDriver driver;
    String url = "https://www.google.com/";


    @BeforeClass
    public void SetUpTests() {

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //Navigate to url
        driver.navigate().to(url);
        //Maximize the browser window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void CleanUpDriver() throws Exception {
        try {

            driver.quit();

        }catch (Exception ex){

            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

**Link Iterator test inheriting BaseTest**

```
package tests;

import google.GoogleLandingPage;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Saifur on 5/30/2015.
 */
public class LinksIteratorTests extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void IterateOverLinks(){
        GoogleLandingPage google = new GoogleLandingPage(driver);

        List<WebElement> elementList = google.ListOfLinks;

        for (int i=0;i<elementList.size(); i++){
            elementList.get(i).click();
            //possibly do something else to go back to the previous page
            driver.navigate().back();
        }
    }
}
```

> *Note: I am using TestNG to maintain the tests and please note for lazy loading page you may need to add some explicit wait if necessary*

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! I will work on this. Leaving bounty open until end so the question still gets attention, but I will award it to someone. Thanks

Comment: Sure! I also have provided a github link where the full concept of *PageFactory* is clearly implemented. You can take a look if you want

Comment: Nice page pattern.  Great example. :-)

Comment: @djangofan Appreciate that!

Comment: The simple answer is yes, but it's not easy.

Comment: Glad you liked it. It's one of the widely used pattern for selenium

Comment: Please upvote the other answer as well. I wish I could give the bounty to both of you.

Comment: @user3735633 Of course. I care about giving credits to people who deserve it